# Basic Issue with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js and started with some basic examples. But I am stuck. Below is my JS code(openHtml.js) .

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("MyApp",[]);
    app.controller("MyAppController",function($scope){
      $scope.message = "It is a message";
    });
}());
```

My HTML is like below

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyAppController">
        <label>{{messsage}}</label>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="openHtml.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the message is not getting displayed in the html. Any idea why ?

The Jfiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/Lx7fuchn/

Comment: Does your console say anything in particular?

Comment: nope no message or error

Comment: Change your question. It is very generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misspelled "message" in your HTML (one "s" too many")

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyAppController">
    <label>{{message}}</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You put 3 "S" in your html template... Try with 2, like in your controller :p

```
$scope.message = "It is a message"; 
<label>{{messsage}}</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyAppController">
        <label>{{message}}</label>
    </div>
```

Wrong expression {{messsage}}

Also you can write your module and the controller just plain:

```
angular.module("MyApp",[])
.controller("MyAppController",function($scope){
  $scope.message = "It is a message";
});
```